# Javascript Closure is Preserving Value of This Keyword Even Though Call Site is Different

Tags: javascript

While I was creating a module I came up with a small technique to remove event listeners and the way I coded it, I actually thought it might not work and it did. Now, I am not clueless with what the `this` keyword is and how it works, I know what execution context is, and I understand that `this` is determined at invocation time.

With that out of the way I have a simplified piece of code that illustrates the point I am confused about. The reason I am confused is that the closure seems to be binding the value of `this`

```js
const obj = {
    foo() {
      console.log(this)
    },
    bar() {
      const context = { ctx: this, baz: this.foo }
      const modal = Modal(context)
      modal.open()
    }
}

function Modal(ctx) {
    // this closes over ctx
    function open() {
      // here is where I am a bit confused, the call site is function open()
      // yet `this` is preserved as the above owner object
      ctx.baz() // logs the above owner object
      // but why is this not lost like the second example below.
    }

    return { open }
}

obj.bar()
```

Essentially I am passing `this` for the object into the `Modal()` function. In the above example it is possible to do a little bit more but here is a simplified example for what is going on above

```js
const obj = {
    foo() {
      console.log(this)
    },
    bar() {
      const modal = Modal(this)
      modal.open()
    }
}

function Modal(ctx) {
    function open() {
      ctx.foo()
    }

    return { open }
}

obj.bar()
```

To make this even more confusing lets modify the above example slightly with destructuring.

```js
const obj = {
    foo() {
      console.log(this)
    },
    bar() {
      const context = { ctx: this, baz: this.foo }
      const modal = module(context)
      modal.open()
    }
}

function module({ ctx, baz }) {
    function open() {
      baz() // now the binding is gone and logs window
    }
    
    return { open }
}
obj.bar() // logs window
```

If we did this the context would be lost since `obj.foo` is a reference to a function being called from the window

```js
const obj = { 
  foo() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

const bar = obj.foo // bind would need to be used
bar() // window
```

I did my best to try to explain this as clear as possible.  Although the code works how I want, I was expecting the context to be lost in `function open()` in the first example as it is lost in the second example. Would this example I came up with above be more bulletproof using call, or bind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What determines the value of `this` is not who the caller is, but *how the call looks* at the call site.

```js
'use strict'

const obj = {
  hello: 'I am obj',
  printThis () {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

// logs obj
obj.printThis()

// logs undefined (window in non-strict mode)
const fn = obj.printThis
fn()

// logs obj
const fn2 = obj.printThis.bind(obj)
fn2()

// logs obj2
const obj2 = {
  hello: 'I am obj2',
  printThis: obj.printThis
}
obj2.printThis()

// logs obj3
const obj3 = {
  hello: 'I am obj3'
}
obj.printThis.call(obj3)
```

This is because unless you use `.call`/`.apply`/`.bind` to manually set what `this` should be, it is determined by looking at whether *the call itself* looks like `x.y()`.

If it does, then `y` is called with `x` as its `this`. Otherwise, it is called with `undefined` (or `window` in non-strict mode) as `this`.

```js
    obj.printThis()
//  ^^^-------------- this is obj

    fn()
// ^----------------- no this given

    fn2()
// ^----------------- no this given, but fn2 was already bound to obj

    obj2.printThis()
//  ^^^^------------- this is obj2

    obj.printThis.call(obj3)
//                     ^^^^-- this is obj3 (explicitly)
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- well, in fact this is a call to the function
//                  Function.prototype.call, with obj.printThis as
//                  this and obj3 as argument ;-)
```

This is different with arrow functions, though. They don't have their own `this` at all, instead `this` behaves like any other variable closed over from the surrounding scope of their definition (also *not* call site).

---

Let's go over your example again then:

1. You call `obj.bar()` (resulting in its `this` being `obj`).
2. `bar` creates an object `context` as follows:

```js
context = {
  ctx: obj // because this === obj
  baz: function () { console.log(this) } // the same as obj.foo
}
```

3. You call `Modal(context)`. This returns an object with an `open` function in it. You store it in `modal`.
4. You call `modal.open()` (resulting in its `this` being `modal`).
5. `open` calls `ctx.baz()`. **`open`'s `this` being `modal` has no relevance here, you are not referencing the keyword `this`, instead you have a call `ctx.baz()` which means calling the function `function () { console.log(this) }` with a `this` of `ctx`** (which is the same as the `context` previously created in `bar`).

So, to recap: At point 5 we have `ctx.baz === obj.foo`, but if you write `obj.foo()` then you call the function with `obj` as `this` (because you wrote `obj.` in front), but if you write `ctx.baz()` then you call the same function with `ctx` as `this` (because you wrote `ctx.` in front).

Comment: I understand your examples, but in my example `function Modal(ctx)` takes in a context object. The context object is added inside of an object method so `this` is pointing to `obj` at the time `Modal()` is called. In Modal() the open function has ctx.baz() because I am taking the baz method off of the passed ctx param. So in the object method bar() `this` is `obj` and am I right in assuming that once the closure is formed it remembers what `this` is? I edited my post, doing almost the same thing with destructuring causes the example to not work

Comment: You do `ctx.baz()`, so `ctx` is `this` for `baz`/ `foo`. See my examples. The way you call the function decides its `this` (what's preceding the last `.` in the call expression). It does not matter who the caller is and whether it is `open` or something else.

Comment: in `obj.bar()` basically I pass `this` into the `Modal()` function, since a function is returned from `Modal()` which references `ctx` we get a closure. It seems like my example relates to your `// logs obj2` example. I posted a simplified example above, would `function Module()` maybe be better used with bind or apply rather than using a closure?

Comment: I added another explanation at the end of my post. - "in obj.bar() basically I pass this into the Modal() function" << what do you mean? I'm confused. Yes you pass it as `context.ctx`, i.e. `ctx.ctx` inside of `Modal`, but you afterwards don't do `ctx.ctx.foo()` or `ctx.baz.call(ctx.ctx)`, instead you do `ctx.baz()`... so it does't matter what you set `context.ctx` to, as it's nowhere used...

Comment: And "why is it not lost as in the example below" - because in the example where it's lost, you simply do `baz()`, with no `something.` in front! But where it works, you have `ctx.` in front, causing `this` to be `ctx`.

Comment: Also I'm a bit confused what you actually _want_ to happen. Do you want to have `this` in `foo` as `obj` at the end, or as the `{ ctx: obj, baz: obj.foo }` object (which is the case in your very first example)? If you wanted the former, you could do `const context = { ctx: this, baz: this.foo.bind(this) }`, and if you wanted the latter, you could do `const context = { ctx: this }; context.baz = this.foo.bind(context)`.

Comment: I just went over your updated answer and I get it. The thing that was confusing me was the fact inside of open it remembered the correct this. If we run `Modal(this)` from the object method, and `this` is the object then essentially we just passed the object into the modal function. For whatever reason since function open() is a regular function, i expected the default window binding, that is I didnt expect it to remember the proper this due to closure

Comment: Since you call `open` as `modal.open()` (prefixed with `modal.`), its `this` gets set to `modal`. But that doesn't matter for `foo`/`baz`, as that's an entirely different function. In fact there is nowhere inside of your `open` function that you ever reference its `this`. - Also: "essentially we just passed the object into the modal function" << yes but not as `this` - as `ctx`.